# Spring Integration and Tomcat solution vs Websphere MDB solution: functionality?

Tags: spring, websphere, message-driven-bean, spring-integration

We're looking at the choice between implementing an enterprise integration solution in either:

- Spring/Spring Integration/JMS/Spring Web MVC
- Websphere Application Server/MDB/Spring

What are the pros/cons?

Especially interested in what WAS/MDB solution is functionally better at.

Cheers

Paul

Comment: I don't really get what's the equivalent of Spring Integration in the second version?

Comment: a) when you mention above framework/technologies, do u mean only integration you need is for JAVA based application. Because all above systems are JAVA based. b) U mention above WAS, are u trying to include WAS only for just integration purpose or is it already present into your software stack. Remember WAS is expensive application server. c) You seems to be mixing unrelated technologies together. WAS is pure J2EE server which has built in JMS provider. MDB and JMS are J2EE standards. Spring is dependency-injection oriented framework which helps to manage the inter-dependency between objects.

Comment: d) Having said all above, you need to concentrate/elaborate more on your current/future integration requirements. Are you looking only java based modules interaction? Are you looking for asynchronous communication?  e) Generally in java based applications, for synchronous communication, web service call is preferred and for asynchronous communication, JMS call is preferred. for both web service and JMS implementation, you got plenty of reliable open source systems like AXIS and Active MQ etc.

Comment: @abologh -- Message driven beans consuming messages off a JMS queue is the integration method in the WAS solution.

Comment: @ag112 -- our integration methods are JMS (Websphere MQ) and file-based. Spring Integration offers good mechanisms to write event-driven systems using these transports. See http://www.springsource.org/spring-integration

Comment: @Paul McKenzie- I understand that spring Integration offers functionality over existing integration pattern...however how about this, your applications' communicating application(whether external/internal) may or may not have spring framework or for that matter, may not be implemented in java....so firstly you should concentrate on your integration requirements before zeroing on a particular framework....if you have already done so, then spring integration can be good framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only thing you need in your entire project from the Java EE Specification is to get messages from a JMS provider, I suggest you to not use WebSphere App Server. Go with Tomcat+Basic Spring JMS Template. Simple, free, lightweight.

Websphere will bring a level of complexity you don't need. Stay away from heavy weight app server. But if you need more fancy Transaction management ( XA between JMS and a DB) then get a real Java EE App Server.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but in a large corporate environment we don't always get what we want.